# Why does it make sense to talk about the Galois group of this polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

This question is in reference to an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3632266/432910) I received from a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3632050/432910).

The answer talks about a cubic polynomial $p(x)$ over a (possibly non-perfect) field $F$ which factors over a splitting field as $p(x) = (x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not neccesarily distinct, and we are trying to determine if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be in $F$.

My main hangup is the answer talks about the Galois group of $p(x)$, but Dummit only defines the Galois group of a *separable* polynomial, and only makes an extension of the definition to inseparable polynomials in the case of polynomials over perfect fields. So what is meant by the Galois group of an inseparable polynomial over a non-perfect field? Is it just the automorphism group of the splitting field $K$ of $p(x)$ over $F$, even if $K/F$ is not Galois?

Comment: For Galois groups of non-separable polynomials see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97596/galois-group-of-a-non-separable-polynomial?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. I saw that question before I posted but was not sure how it applied. I will study it some more.

Comment: The polynomial $x^3 - t$ over $F = \mathbf{F}_3(t)$ has a multiple root and yet has no linear factor (here $\alpha = \beta$ does not lie in $F$).